Show that $| \sum_{0 < \gamma \le T} x^{\rho} | \gg \sum_{0 < \gamma \le T} x^{\beta}$.
In Gonek's paper it is claimed without proof the following:
Let $\rho = \beta + i \gamma $ be zeros of Riemann zeta function and $\beta_T = \max_{0 < \gamma \le T} \beta $. Then we deduce from Dirichlet's theorem
on Diophantine approximation that there exist arbitrarily large values of $x$ for
which $$| \sum_{0 < \gamma \le T} x^{\rho} | \gg \sum_{0 < \gamma \le T} x^{\beta} >  x^{\beta_T}. $$
How is the first inequality deduced? (The only Dirichlet's theorem I know is approximation of real numbers by rational numbers and it seems to be irrelevant; and nothing on "Dirichlet's theorem on Diophantine approximation" is available on the Internet.)

Dirichlet's theorem says that you can approximate a bunch of common multiples of fixed real numbers by integers without any conditions on the real numbers and even gives a quantitative bound on the approximation height - it is Theorem 8.2 page 184 in Titchmarsh RZ book; here this means that if $\rho=\beta+i\gamma, 0 < \gamma \le T$ and $\epsilon$ fixed you can find arbitrarily high $x$ st $|\gamma\log x /(2\pi)-n_{\gamma}| < \epsilon$ for all $\gamma$ as above which means that $x^{i\gamma}$ is about $1$ so $x^{\rho}$ is about $x^{\beta}$ - good exercise to figure it yourself fully riguorulsy

Thanks a lot @Conrad, you have helped me several times and each meant a lot to me. I wish you the best in your life :)

Happy to be of help and thank you for your kind words -

Let $\rho_1=\beta_1+i\gamma_1,\rho_2=\beta_2+i\gamma_2,\dots,\rho_N=\beta_N+i\gamma_N$ be the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ satisfying $0\le\gamma\le T$. Then by Dirichlet's theorem, for each $\varepsilon>0$ and $Q>0$, there exists integers $h\ge Q$ and $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_N$ such that
$$
\left|{h\gamma_k\over2\pi}-q_k\right|<\varepsilon\quad k=1,2,\dots,N
$$
Hence, we have $e^{ih\gamma_k}=e^{i(h\gamma_k-2\pi q_k)}=e^{O(\varepsilon)}=1+O(\varepsilon)$, so when $x=e^h$, there is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^Nx^{\rho_k}=\sum_{k=1}^Nx^{\beta_k}[1+O(\varepsilon)].
$$
Consequently, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^Nx^{\rho_k}\right|\gg\sum_{k=1}^Nx^{\beta_k}.
$$
